# How to enable/disable user in Keycloak Admin Client

Tags: keycloak

In the examples I've found for the Keycloak Admin Client, a method called "setEnabled" in the UserRepresentation class is mentioned to enable/disable the user.

Unfortunately, this method seemed to be removed in the latest versions, as the method is also not listed in the JavaDocs anymore.

So, my question is: how can I enable/disable a user in the newest versions of the Keycloak Admin Client (3.4.3.Final)?

Thanks and best regards, Chris

Comment: I still can see it in the docs for that version: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.4/javadocs/org/keycloak/representations/idm/UserRepresentation.html#setEnabled-java.lang.Boolean-

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is clearly possible to do using the API:

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" --data "{\"enabled\": false}" "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/[my-realm]/users/[user-id]"
```

Answer (score 11):

Works on Keycloak-admin-client version 4.8.3.Final

```
// connect to keycloak server
Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
        .serverUrl(AUTHURL)
        .realm(REALM)
        .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD) // "password"
        .clientId(CLIENTID)
        .clientSecret(SECRETKEY)
        .username(ADMIN_USERNAME)
        .password(ADMIN_PASSWORD)
        .build();

// get user resource
RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm(REALM);
UsersResource userRessource = realmResource.users();

// fetch an existing user
UserRepresentation user = userRessource.get(userId).toRepresentation();

// change user
user.setEnabled(true);

// update
userRessource.get(userId).update(user);
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution: The issue was that different Java packages with a UserRepresentation class exist and I imported the wrong one. The right one is 
`org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation` and this also includes a function `setEnabled()`.

Thanks a lot for comments!

Answer (score 0):

According to Azat Answer, You can update any properties of Keycloak user by Admin client library without any endpoint call. It works for me.